# unable to identify pop up window in android UIautomator viewer

Tags: android, appium, uiautomatorviewer

[image]I want to inspect the pop up window as shown in the screenshot

The picture that is attached is of Android app. I am trying to inspect with UIAutomator viewer of Android. In it I can't inspect the pop up window that is on the foreground. I want to click on dismiss in that window

Please suggest whether this can be detected or not or any other tool to be used

thanks for your time[image]

Comment: Can you please attach screen shot from UIAutomator with visible elements?

Comment: @Vinod this is the screenshot which has all the visible elements. The dismiss button is not getting inspected but the background elements do

Comment: I am talking about the screen shot of UIAutomator along with visible elements and child elements hierarchy.

Comment: This "Dismiss" pop up does not seem to be system pop-up because UIAutomator is not able to identiy. Did you try `driver.switchTO()` ??

Comment: yes I did. I am getting "not yet implemented"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now this is a known issue with UiAutomator that [has been reporte](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=93268)d but does not have any workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Make your popup window as `Focusable` "`true`". See the last property in **PoupWindow** constructor.

Example:

```
PopupWindow popupWindowTwo = new PopupWindow(timelineGuidanceDialog, 400, 400, **true**);

popupWindow.showAsDropDown(eventButtonView, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Surprisingly, this really works. It also works if you do that via the setter `popWindow.setFocusable(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find few possible solutions:

A. Seems like android alert notifications spawn in a different context. Meaning the primary solution that works for me is to change package id to "android". For example:

```
mAppiumDriver.findElementById("android:id/button").click();
```

B. Another workaround is using focus gained by alert popup. Windows gets focused, meaning you can still send keyboard input to no specific element. You can use TAB / DPAD keys to navigate around and ENTER to "click" on specific View.